# How to call JS file/React code within Flask project? getting errors

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm currently trying to put together a Flask + React project. Just a simple Flask project, with some react code for the js part.

I have had some difficulty getting the js file (which contains the react code) to run at all in the project.

This is my project structure, standard for flask:
[image]

The app route is defined in the routes.py file in the project root; right now, just a single home page (the html file)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/qubits")
def qubits():
    return render_template('qubits.html')
    # http://localhost:5000/qubits

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

The html file is pretty simple, and it is linking properly to my css (im able to pull in css elements fine). Its just the js file thats not returning any divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>nstem</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/nstem.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="indexBox1"></div>
      <h1>: )</h1>
      <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/index.js') }}"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, nothing is being returned on the webpage from these two js files:

```
*index.js*

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './nstem.css';
import Qubit from './qubits';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Qubit />,

  document.getElementById('root')
);


* qubits.js *
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';

function Qubit() {

  const section = 'lists';

  return (
    <div>Allah'u'abha</div>
  );
}

export default Qubit;
```

Im pretty stumped; ive played with this so much today and cant figure out where the gap is. Please help, and thanks so much.

Comment: Nothing is returned as in? Are you getting the right data in the network tab on the browser? Is you js file getting transpiled to ES5 may be?

Comment: new to this kind of development so bear with me. . . In the sources, the index.js file is showing up, but it appears empty. The qubits.js file isnt showing up at all. hope that is helpful.

Comment: to be clear, nothing is showing up on the page either. I added the react dependencies at the top of the html file, and changed the type from "text/javascript" to "text/babel" and even removed the type, but still nothing,

Comment: the files are both in the sources in the browser now, but both are still showing up as empty

Comment: other js files are working, just not the react ones

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>nstem</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/nstem.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="indexBox1"></div>
      <h1>: )</h1>

      {/**/}
      <div id="root"></div>
      We call this a “root” DOM node because everything inside it will be managed by React DOM.
      {/**/}

      <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/index.js') }}"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check the html template file DOM node is missing.

Comment: other js files are working, just not the react ones